# How to prove that $P(A \cap B) \ge 0$ given that $A\subseteq\Omega$ and $B\subseteq\Omega$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, bayes-theorem

> Let $(\Omega,\,P(\cdot))$ denote a probability space and suppose that %B% is an event in this space where $P(B)>0$. Prove $P(A|B)\ge0$ for all events $A\subseteq\Omega$.

So far I've done:

Using Bayes Theorem, $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

The question tells us that $P(B) > 0$, so we just have to prove that $P(A \cap B)\ge0$.

I think intuitively it makes sense that $A \cap B$ is non-negative since $A\subseteq\Omega$ and $B\subseteq\Omega$, but I'm not sure how to formally prove it.

Comment: A probability measure must take its values from the interval $[0,1]$. In particular, it's always nonnegative.

Comment: Is it also possible to prove that the cardinality of $A \cap B \geq 0$ ?

Comment: No, actually $A\cap B$ can be empty, but in this case of course $P(A|B)=0$.

Comment: @dudeguyguerilla : I wonder if you have a misconception about “cardinality” and its role. What is your definition of “cardinality”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a fraction of real numbers  $\dfrac{a}{b}$ with $b\neq 0$ is negative if and only if either $a$ or $b$ is negative but not if both have the same sign.

You have already used Bayes theorem to see that $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. Since $P(B) > 0$ the only way to obtain a negative fraction would be if $P(A\cap B)<0$. But $P$ is a probability measure so it always takes values in $[0,1]$. Hence the whole fraction is positive and so $P(A|B)$.

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ are sets also the intersection is a set and the cardinality is a map which assigns to any set its number of elements which is a non-negative integer by definition.